# HQL/Hive Missing EOF in LIMIT query

Tags: sql, hive, hql

i'm new to HQL and was wondering the reason of the error below:
I was selecting the whole database which had ~9 millions of records so I was trying to get it chunk by chunk. Therefore I tried:

Everything worked fine when I used:

`SELECT * FROM tableABC ORDER BY tableABC.ID LIMIT 10; //Select everything from the table with total 10 rows`

However, when I tried to get them with:

`SELECT * FROM tableABC ORDER BY tableABC.ID LIMIT 0,10; //Select everything from the table from row 0 to total 10 rows`

I kept getting the error of "FAILED: ParseException line 1:111 missing EOF at ',' near '0')". I tried using LIMIT with OFFSET, and it still showed the same error about EOF.

May I know what would be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Limit with two arguments should work in **hive 2.0.0** or higher version. Could you please check your hive version using `select version()` and find the root cause for yourself?

If your hive is lower than 2, you can use below SQL to get the data you want. I am using row_number() to generate sequential numbers and then putting a filter on it. This may be little slower than limit x,y but shouldn't be too much different.

```
select id,col_1, col_2...
from (
    select id, col_1, col_2, ... , row_number() OVER (ORDER by id) as rownum    from tableABC
    ) rs
where rownum between 0 and 50
```

Comment: Yes you are right, my current Hive version doesn't support OFFSET. May I know why there is a "rs" in the query?

Comment: `rs`  aka resultset is the alias given to the subquery. in hive you should alias every subqueries so that they can be identified.